# Strip Images from Pasteboard

Tags: image, uitextview, copy-paste, nsattributedstring, uipasteboard

Can someone please guide how I can strip images from attributed text on the pasteboard?

EXAMPLE

I have a UITextView that supports NSAttributedString. If I allow a user to paste something from the pasteboard that includes an image (say a picture and some text that was copied from a web page in the Safari app), it will crash my app when I try to save it:

```
*** Assertion failure in -[NSHTMLReader _addAttachmentForElement:URL:needsParagraph:usePlaceholder:], /SourceCache/UIFoundation_Sim/UIFoundation-78/UIFoundation/TextSystem/NSHTMLReader.m:1478
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Unable to find missing_image.tiff!'
```

This only occurs when an image is part of the source copy. Why it refers to tiff I don't know, as the source images I've been testing with are jpg and png.

As described in a [related post with slightly different goal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13301058/pasting-image-into-uitextview-causes-crash), my workaround to avoid the crash is to force the pasteboard to a regular string:

```
- (void)paste:(id)sender
{
    UIPasteboard *pasteBoard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
    NSString *string = pasteBoard.string;
    [self insertText:string];
}
```

This does prevent a crash, but it also prevents the user from pasting any formatted text. Say bold, or italic that may have come from the Mail app.

So best I can tell, I need to strip any images from the pasteboard so as to allow the text formatting to be retained. Thanks for your help.