# How to not copy images into UITextView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

My app uses `UITextView` to get some input from user, I use Xcode4.5 simulator for Ipad 5.1 , ARC

If user tries to copy&paste a text with  bulletining or image ,  I get following error:

```
 Mapping '/Users/user/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Library/Caches/com.apple.keyboards/images/1848901318' failed: 'Cannot allocate memory' (12)

GuardMalloc[W]: Failed to VM allocate 16384 bytes
GuardMalloc[W]: Explicitly trapping into debugger!!!
```

I tired below to user to prevent using any odd chars or images from pasting but couldnt make it work, it doesnt even fire.

```
- (void)paste:(id)sender {
    UIPasteboard *pasteBoard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
    NSString *string = pasteBoard.string;
    NSLog(@"Pasteboard string: %@", string);
    [self.wodDescription insertText:string]; //woddesription is the textview
}
```

Why do I get above error? What is the best way to fix this crash?

Comment: Have you tried restricting characters with NSCharacterSet?

Comment: I dont know what part of the string to trim , bizarre chars could be in any part of the text though, and images still be there

Comment: Your question is titled "how to not copy", but aren't you really asking how to not paste as your method suggests? Perhaps subtle, but it is different.

Answer (score -1):

I think I can address your issue by looking at how not to paste, as opposed to how not to copy with [this existing thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13317175/306212):

```
- (void)paste:(id)sender
{
    UIPasteboard *pasteBoard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
    NSString *string = pasteBoard.string;
    [self insertText:string];
}
```

Comment: Isn't this effectively the same code as is already in OP's question? The only things you're missing are the `NSLog` (which won't have an effect on the paste) and the `wodDescription` property, which is specific to OP's implementation (and is mostly irrelevant to the point).

Comment: Space Dust does not say if he's trying to subclass UITextView. If so the self.woDDesctription could be an issue. I am using the code above with no issue in my own project. I did not just read a a topic and paste it. I'm sharing first hand experience of a solution that addresses what I understand the question to be.